# How to live stream stock price using python

Tags: python, stock

At first I want to find some API, but I have searched on the internet and didn't find anything 
 really helpful.

"Real time" I mean live stream the stock price on a webpage without a refresh.

If there is not such API, would my following method be a good way to implement this?
1. Python side, call yahoo finance api to get the most recent price.
2. Browser side, use ajax to constantly call server side to get the price and display the price. More specifically, I am thinking to use setInterval in jquery to achieve this.

How does this approach look?

Actually this is not specific to stock price data, any website that need to constantly retrieve data from server side need to consider this problem. For example google chat, facebook news feed, and so on. Can anybody tell me in general how to achieve live streaming data from server to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use a push architecture. You could take a look at [APE - Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.html).

You could also take a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), a realtime application framework for Node.JS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there are a few options. Could you give me a little more information about which is better in what situation? I don't want to spend too much time on one approach just in order to find the other one is better

Comment: APE provides a push architecture while Socket.IO provides a realtime application framework in the sense that through Socket.IO you achieve two way communication. If I were you, I would give a try to Socket.IO.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a Push API.  These days you should probably use http://www.websocket.org/

Comment: These days? I think you're going to still need to wait a few years for that... :(

Comment: The poster didn't specify more on his deployment restrictions, but given that there are implementations of websocket using Flash I'm wondering what browsers you would want to support today that couldn't be made to work with either native or flash-based websockets.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a rest API for real time, its inefficient to constantly "pull" the live price. Instead you want a service that will "push" changes to you whenever new trades are executed on the exchange. This is done with a websocket, which is a type of API but it is definitely different from a rest API. [This article discusses](http://blog.intrinio.com/stock-prices-from-intrinio/) the difference.

[Intrinio](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/web_api) provides a real-time websocket and you can access it via Python using [this SDK on Github](https://github.com/jorymorrison/real-time-intrinio-python). You can access the same data via rest API using [this package in Python](https://github.com/nhedlund/intrinio). If you try them both you will see the architecture doesn't make sense with a rest API.

[This video shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fmd6exi-4t8) the trades coming in- trades don't execute on the market at regular intervals, it's completely sporadic. Instead of constantly "asking" the server for the data, it's better to "listen". This is called top of the book, meaning you get the newest trades as they come in from the top.